# Practice Free Response (Update)

Tags: java

Why errors occur in part B?

Instructions:
The following Numbers class will be used to analyze and retrieve sets of numbers.

```
public class Numbers
{
/** @param nums is a positive non-decimal value
* Precondition: nums>=0
* @return false if the sum of digit divisors of num is odd
* @return true if the sum of the digit divisors of num is even
*/
public static boolean isSilly(int value)
{
/* to be implemented in part(a) */
}

/* @param count is a positive non-decimal value
* Precondition: count >0
* @return an array containing count Silly numbers
*/
public static int[] getSomeSillyNumbers(int count)
{
*/ to be implemented in part(b) */
}
// There may be varialbes/fields,constructors, and methods that are not shown.
}
```

A. Write the Numbers method isSilly(), as started below. isSilly() will be an integer and determine if the integer is Silly or not Silly.

A Silly number is any number that has a digit divisor sum that is even. The sum must be greater than zero.

The call isSilly(12) would return false as 12 has a digit divisor sum of 3 - [1,2] which is odd.

```
/** @param num is a positive non-decimal value
* Precondition: value >=0
* @return false if the sum of digit divisor of num is odd
@return true if the sum of the digit divisor of the num is even
*/
```

**What I have done for A**

```
public static boolean isSilly(int value)
{   
    int sum = 0;
    while (value > 0)
    {
        sum = sum + value % 10;
        value = value / 10;
    }
    if (sum%2==0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

B. Write the Numbers method getSomeSillyNumbers(), as started below.
getSomeSillyNumbers() will recieve a count of how many Silly Numbers to return.

The call getSomeSillyNumbers(3) would return [2,4,6].

You must call the method from part a, assuming the method works as specified regardless of what you wrote.

```
/* @param count is a positive non-decimal value
* Precondition: stop>0
* @return an array containing count Silly numbers
*/
```

**What I have done for B**

```
public static int[] getSomeSillyNumbers(int count)
{   int[] getSomeSillyNumbers = new int[count];
    while(count!=0)
    {

        if(isSilly(count))
        {
            int i=0;
            getSomeSillyNumbers[i]=count;
            i++;

        }

        count --;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getSomeSillyNumbers));
    return getSomeSillyNumbers;
}
```

**Update**

My entire code is this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Numbers
{
    public static boolean isSilly(int value)
    {   
        int sum = 0;
        while (value > 0)
        {
            sum = sum + value % 10;
            value = value / 10;
        }
        if (sum%2==0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public static int[] getSomeSillyNumbers(int count)
    {   int[] getSomeSillyNumbers = new int[count];
        int i=0;
        while(count!=0)
        {            
            if(isSilly(count))
            {
                getSomeSillyNumbers[i]=count;
                i++;
            }
            count--;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getSomeSillyNumbers));
        return getSomeSillyNumbers;
    }
}
```

with a runner:

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
public class NumbersRunner
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Numbers runner = new Numbers();
        runner.isSilly(12);
        runner.isSilly(15);
        runner.isSilly(26);
        runner.isSilly(8);
        runner.isSilly(1234);
        runner.getSomeSillyNumbers(3);
        runner.getSomeSillyNumbers(15);
    }
}
```

I am getting:

```
[2, 0, 0]
[15, 13, 11, 8, 6, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

When I should be getting

```
[2,4,6]
[2,4,6,8,11,15,20,22,24,26,28,32,33,40,42]
```

Comment: You are calling `isSilly(count)` and only silly numbers from 3 to 1 is 2. You should not use `count` when calling isSilly. Instead you should call isSilly until you have that many silly numbers

Comment: where have you gone to @john-hanson ?

Comment: I have updated, @ScaryWombat

Comment: did you try debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following errors are there in part `B`:

- You are re-creating `int[] getSomeSillyNumbers` every time in line `int[] getSomeSillyNumbers = new int[count];` inside the loop.So, it will always have only 1 value i.e. latest value of `count`. **To solve it,** create `getSomeSillyNumbers` array outside the loop i.e. place line `int[] getSomeSillyNumbers = new int[count];` before `while` loop.
- Declaration of `i` is local in line `int i=0;` in while loop. So it is getting re-created every time and initialized with `0`. **To solve it,** place line `int i=0;` before the while loop.

**Note:** I assume that `getSomeSillyNumbers();` in return line is another method. If not then use is improper.

Comment: Thank you, but my output is still only getting [2,0,0] instead of [2,4,6]

Answer (score 0):

Move the

```
int[] getSomeSillyNumbers = new int[count];
```

to before your `while` statement

then at the bottom of your code, you will have have visibility of this variable and you can

replace

```
return getSomeSillyNumbers();
```

with

```
return getSomeSillyNumbers;  // the variable
```

**Note**

If you declare a variable with a block with curly braces then the variable is only visible within that block

Comment: I fixed that, but my output is still off.

Comment: Based upon the answer, where is `int i=0;` declared and what did I say about it?  Hint: move it to outside of your while block